# Как работает программа, определяющая есть ли в строке abba?

Tags: c, алгоритм, функции, рекурсия

Есть такая программа, пользователь должен ввести строку и программа должна определить есть ли в строке такое сочитание символов: abba. ПРограмма рабочая, но я не могу понять как именно она работает, как проверяется, что символы стоят по порядку.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int START(void);
int abba(void);


int getchar1(void) {
    char in;
    in = getchar();
    return in;
}

int START(void) {
    int c = getchar1();
    if (c == 'a')
        return abba();
    return 1;
}

int abba(void) {
    int c = getchar1();
    if (c == 'a')
        return abba();
    if (c != 'b')
        return 1;

    c = getchar1();
    if (c == 'a')
        return abba();
    if (c != 'b')
        return 1;

    c = getchar();
    if (c == 'b')
        return abba();
    if (c != 'a')
        return 1;

    printf("abba found\n");
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    printf("\n*start*\n");
    while (START());
    printf("*the end*\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос симметричности строк, наверное 10-тый в этом году

Comment: Программа **НЕ "рабочая"**, т.е. она не делает то, что вы думаете она делает. Пожалуйста, не сопровождайте вопросы здесь утверждениями вроде "программа рабочая". Если вы не в состоянии самостоятельно разобраться с тем, как работает программа, это автоматически означает, что делать утверждения о работоспособности программы вы не в праве.

Comment: @AnT Что за дурацкое утверждение. Кто угодно может делать утверждения о работоспособности программы. Тысячи тестеров и испытателей делают обоснованные и корректные утверждения о программах, без всяких разбирательств, как оно работает и даже не имея кода.

Comment: @Эникейщик: Не надо смешивать несмешиваемое. Утверждения о работоспособности от тестировщиков и утверждения о работоспособности в контексте исчерпывающего анализа кода - очень разные вещи. В данном случае речь идет именно о втором. Если уж на то пошло, то никаких "утверждений о работоспособности" внешние тестировщики в общем случае делать не могут вообще. Все прекрасно понимают, что их утверждения - лишь слепые отчеты о прохождении тестов.

Comment: @AnT Не вижу разницы - есть код, запустил - работает. Как? А хэ зэ. Как вы проверяете работоспособность кода, если не тестами? Работоспособность и есть прохождение тестов. Никого не интересует что там происходит внутри кода, кроме тех, кто его пишет и делает ревью (да и их не всегда).

Comment: @Эникейщик: В данном случае мы как раз и наблюдаем "тестировщика", который замыленным взглядом выдал желаемое за действительное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто забавный рекурсивный вызов.

`START()` проверяет символ. Если не `a`, возвращает 1, и цикл вызывает ее заново.

```
int abba(void)
{
    int c = getchar1();
    if (c == 'a')         // Это *может* быть a..abba - проверяем заново.
        return abba();
    if (c != 'b')         // После a не b - значит, не abba, возврат 1 в START
        return 1;
                          // Нашли ab
    c = getchar1(); 
    if (c == 'a')         // Если очередной символ - a, это может быть начало abba -
        return abba();    // вызываем рекурсивно
    if (c != 'b')         // Если не a и не b - то, понятно, это не abba, возврат 1 в START
        return 1;
                          // Нашли abb
    c = getchar();
    if (c == 'b')         // abbb - проверка заново
        return abba();
    if (c != 'a')         // abx - не оно; все начинаем сначала (в START)
        return 1;
                          // Сюда попадаем только для abba
    printf("abba found\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Примерно так...

Comment: спасибо огромное, теперь все понятно

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, программа НЕ "рабочая", т.е. она не ищет строку `abba`. Последняя группа `if`

```
c = getchar();
if (c == 'b')
    return abba();
if (c != 'a')
    return 1;
```

полностью противоречит вашему описанию назначения программы. В частности, несложно видеть, что на вход `abbbbba` ваша программа отвечает "abba found". Если ваше описание ожидаемой функциональности верно, то все описание поведения этой программы можно уложить в два слова: *программа некорректна*.

А уж кто тут напортачил - вы или автор кода - вопрос отдельный.

Во-вторых, что же на самом деле делает функция `abba()`? Чтобы добраться до печати "abba found", необходимо, чтобы в момент вызова этой функции во входе содержалась последовательность `bba` - это очевидно из последовательности условий в `abba()`. А вот вызывается функция `abba()` тогда, когда из входа прочитан символ `a` (в `START`) или (!) (благодаря вышеупомянутой группе проверок) когда сама функция `abba()` встретила последовательность `bbb`.

Таким образом, для того, чтобы поиск начался, необходим префикс `a`. Для того, чтобы напечаталось "abba found", необходим суффикс `bba`. А вот для того, чтобы дойти от первого до второго, можно пройти еще через любое число последовательностей `bbb`. То есть ваша программа ищет последовательности вида

```
... a(bbb)bba ...
       ^
       повторяется 0 или более раз
```

т.е. `a`, за которым следует 3n+2 `b` и затем снова `a`.

Также обратите внимание, что последняя `a` в вышеописанной последовательности не вызывает рекурсивного вызова `abba()`, т.е. во входе `abbabba` эта программа найдет только одно `abba`. Правильное это поведение или нет - вопрос к постановке задачи.

---

Возвращаемое значение `return 1` не играет никакой роли, ибо никаких других значений эти функции не возвращают, т.е главный цикл программы - бесконечен. Не ясно, зачем понадобилась функция `getchar1`, при том что она повторяет функциональность `getchar`, но в коде вызывается и `getchar1` и `getchar`. Чисто для запутывания?